# Django 1.8: Help making filenames RELATIVE

Tags: python, django, filenames, relative-path, django-settings

I'm new to Django.  First I'll explain my issue and my logic.  I want to make my filepaths RELATIVE as opposed to the ABSOLUTE they are now so I can work on my laptop and PC and have everything show up as is.
I know I'll have to alter MEDIA_URL in the **settings.py** below.  Does

```
MEDIA_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'articles/static/articles/media/')
STATIC_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'articles/static/')
```

make sense?  I mean logically to me its saying from BASE_DIR which prints to *C:\Users\kevIN3D\Documents\GitHub\articleTestProject\articleTestSite*, would step into *articles/static/articles/media/* or does the fact that

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))
```

is abspath(...) change everything?

---

***settings.py***

```
"""
Django settings for articleTestSite project.
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/
For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/kevIN3D/Documents/GitHub/articleTestProject/articleTestSite/articles/static/articles/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '2u@9=qkari39(465g+u!2t7*9tt_pdv)%155jdgxnki5#jujje'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'articles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'articleTestSite.urls'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'articleTestSite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC-5'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/kevIN3D/Documents/GitHub/articleTestProject/articleTestSite/articles/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

---

***urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/', include('articles.urls')),
    url(r'^$', HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

---

My issue is when I try to use '/' in my declaration it prints out the filename as 'C:\Users\kevIN3D\Documents\GitHub\articleTestProject\articleTestSite\articles/static/' so it uses incorrect slashes for myself.

How do I go about making my page have relative filenames?  I want to be able to work on this between my laptop and my PC, but as it currently stands I can only work on it on my PC because all the filenames are absolute and just give me broken links on my laptop.

Here is a link to the repository [Github Repository](https://github.com/kevinIN3D/articleTestProject).  Please any help would be appreciated, I'm completely stumped.  If someone could get that working, with images and custom CSS and then kind of walk me through what you did.  Its my first time trying to distribute a Django file to more then just the local host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I figured it out,
I was looking at things far to high-level so to speak.  When in reality the answer was just simple.  After giving myself a

```
print(BASE_DIR)
```

and having it spit out **C:\Users\kevIN3D\Documents\GitHub\articlesTestProject\articleTestSite** I realized all I needed to do was append that to my different *ROOT* variables.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/kevIN3D/Documents/GitHub/articleTestProject/articleTestSite/articles/static/articles/'
```

was my old MEDIA_ROOT, this was clearly absolute.  BUT from this I can see that it shares that same filepath as BASE_DIR, so I went from there and

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/kevIN3D/Documents/GitHub/articleTestProject/articleTestSite/articles/static/articles/'
```

became

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'articles/static/articles/').replace('\\', '/') #run replace to convert UNIX slashes on Windows slashes
```

---

---

I had to do the same thing for *STATIC_ROOT*

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/kevIN3D/Documents/GitHub/articleTestProject/articleTestSite/articles/'
```

became

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'articles')
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me explain settings:

### Right wave to separate the path

Pass every folder to the `os.path.join()` method. Example:

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'articles', 'static')
```

### STATIC_URL, MEDIA_URL

This variables are passed to your template context proccessor (if you use `django.template.context_processors.media`) without any changes. This variables are used to make client-side links to your static and media content.

You should set your `STATIC_URL` and `MEDIA_URL` manually. Like that:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Then you can use them in templates:

```
<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}img/logo.png">(...)
```

### STATIC_ROOT, MEDIA_ROOT, STATICFILES_DIRS

`STATIC_ROOT` is used to bring all your static files in one place by `collectstatic` command (if you're using django simple server, you shouldn't care about it).

`STATICFILES_DIRS` is the folder when your django simple server (`manage.py runserver` command) gets files to serve. If you will run `collectstatic` command, evety file from every dir listed in `STATICFILES_DIRS` copied be moved in `STATIC_ROOT`.

`MEDIA_ROOT` is the folder where Django will hold user-uploaded files (`ImageField`, `FileField`)

You should use absolute path in `STATIC_ROOT`, `MEDIA_ROOT`, `STATICFILES_DIRS`:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'example', 'static', 'folder',)
```

Please note. If you have `static` folder in your app folder and your app is listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` this folder will be added to your `STATICFILES_DIRS` automatically.

### Serving static and media files during development

It's really simple just add this lines after your urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ... your patterns...
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And don't forget to include settings:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

### Serving on production server

1. Run `collectstatic` command to bring all your static content in one place.
2. Server your static and media folder using your apache/nginx/etc server:

   Alias /media/ /path/to/your/media
   Alias /static/ /path/to/your/static/

Comment: @Kevin Leegsma, what do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: This doesn't help or I'm not understanding it at all.  

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'articles', 'static').replace('\\', '/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/articles/'
print(STATIC_ROOT)`
Prints: **./articleTestProject/articleTestSite/articles**, rest of path is contained in _STATIC_URL_, leads to '/static/articles/'

`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'articles', 'static', 'articles').replace('\\', '/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
print(MEDIA_ROOT)`
Prints: **./articleTestProject/articleTestSite/articles/static/articles**, rest of path contained in _MEDIA_URL_ leads to the '/media/' subfolder

Comment: But now trying to load any site I get 
**AttributeError at /articles/2/

'tuple' object has no attribute 'resolve'**

Comment: I'm to new to Django to understand archaic answers.  For the most part i've been able to figure out everything/errors on my own.  But this type of error reminds me of _linker_ errors I used to get in C++ that are just confusing to look at.

Comment: Leave your BASE_DIR default `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`. Can you save full traceback from AttributeError somewhere (pastebin, github gists)?

Comment: `STATIC_URL ` is absolutely independent from `STATIC_ROOT` and vice versa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75836/discussion-between-kevin-leegsma-and-daniil).

Comment: I figured it out, solution below.  I was just being dumb.  I was thinking about it waaaay to complex.  So I went back to my original that worked absolute and looked it over looking for the simplest solution.  Printed out `print(BASE_DIR)` and it all fell into place from there.